# Aeson: converting a JSON object to a List of key, value type

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, aeson

I have some JSON fields stored in a database which contain a String -> Double mapping, e.g.:

```json
{
  "some type of thing": 0.45,
  "other type of thing": 0.35,
  "something else": 0.2
}
```

I want to represent this as a `ThingComposition`:

```hs
data ThingType = ThingTypeSome
               | ThingTypeOther
               | ThingTypeUnknown Text

-- | Create a ThingType from a text representation
txtToThing :: Text -> ThingType
txtToThing "some type of thing"  = ThingTypeSome
txtToThing "other type of thing" = ThingTypeOther
txtToThing s                     = ThingTypeUnknown s

-- Deserialise ThingType from JSON text
instance FromJSON ThingType where
  parseJSON val = withText "ThingType" (return . txtToThing) val

data ThingComposition = ThingComposition [(ThingType, Double)]
                      | InvalidThingComposition

instance FromJSON ThingComposition where
  parseJSON val = withObject "ThingComposition"
                             _
                             val
```

The `_` is what I have no idea how to fill out. I've tried something like the following but I can't get the types to align and I can't work out the best way to do this, given that it's possible that the JSON representation won't match the types, but I don't want to create a list of `[(Either String ThingType, Either String Double)]`. How can I parse that the object at the top into the `ThingComposition` type?

```hs
_ = (return . ThingComposition) . map (bimap parseJSON parseJSON) . toList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make some supporting instances for your `ThingType`, then reuse the `FromJSON (HashMap k v)` instance.

```
-- added "deriving Eq" to your declaration; otherwise unchanged
data ThingType = ThingTypeSome
               | ThingTypeOther
               | ThingTypeUnknown Text
               deriving Eq

thingToTxt :: ThingType -> Text
thingToTxt ThingTypeSome = "some type of thing"
thingToTxt ThingTypeOther = "other type of thing"
thingToTxt (ThingTypeUnknown s) = s

instance FromJSONKey ThingType where
    fromJSONKey = FromJSONKeyText txtToThing
instance Hashable ThingType where
    hashWithSalt n = hashWithSalt n . thingToTxt
```

With that supporting code, you now have a `FromJSON` instance for `HashMap ThingType Double`, which is superior in many ways to a `[(ThingType, Double)]`.

Comment: Thanks, that does work, although doesn't completely answer the question -- I would still be curious to know what's missing in the whole I outlined to deserialise the object as mentioned.

Comment: @GTF `foldrWithKey (\k v kvs -> do { d <- parseJSON v; ((txtToThing k, d):) <$> kvs }) (pure [])`

Comment: Ah so I don't have to handle the errors in `parseJSON`? I guess they just `fail` rather than return `Either` or `Maybe` so it's ok type-wise. Thanks.

Comment: @GTF The programmable semicolon in `...parseJSON v; ((txtToThing k, ...` handles the errors in the background. If `parseJSON v` fails, the following `((txtToThing k, ...` is never evaluated.